# CSS Folding Paper Like Menu Issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to build a menu that would have a transition like paper folding, kinda like this one:

[image]

Live Test :  http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-3d-unfolding-menu.html

**Here is my code:**

HTML

```
<nav>
  <li class="hov">Hover Me!
    <ul class="main">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{

}

ul,li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;

}
.main li{
  list-style:none;
  background: blue;
  width:100px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;

  line-height: 30px;
  /*margin-top: -30px;*/

  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;

}

.main li:nth-child(odd){

  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.main li:nth-child(even){

  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.main {

  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.hov:hover .main {

  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
}

.hov:hover li:nth-child(odd){
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  margin-top:0;
}

.hov:hover li:nth-child(even){
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
   margin-top:0;
}

.main li:first-child{
  margin-top:0;
}

.hov{
  position:relative;
  height: 40px;
  width:112px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style:none;
  z-index:2;



}
```

Live DEMO

http://codepen.io/razvan-tudosa/pen/BxgJl

**Question :**

How can I make the sub-menus stick together as in the example?

Comment: `http://codepen.io/razvan-tudosa/pen/BxgJl` Does not work in FF.

Comment: You need to post your code here and not only links, as if links will be dead, your question won't be useful for future visitors, so casting a close vote, hope you add code to your question soon..

Comment: The question is `How can i make the sub-menus don`t stick together ?`

Comment: This question still makes no sense. Tutorial domain. Badly asked. Want Want Want kind of question, not taking care about what to specfically ask about in this CSS domain and the like. Why has it been reopened?

Comment: @hakre lets give him a chance..

Comment: Let's see, however the tutorial has those sub menus sticked together and the demo doesn't. So regardless if the question asks for the one or the other, for both cases an example is given. So what does the question ask for (that is not already answered)?

Comment: That example was to show you what I`m trying to achieve, the code from the CodePen is my trial. The problem is that my sub-menus are not sticking together and I can`t figure out why. I`m sorry I wasn`t that clear in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He want to stik the sub menus.

For doing that edit these css class like down here:

```
.main li:nth-child(even){
  margin-top:-65px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.hov:hover li:nth-child(odd){
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(30px) rotateX(0deg);
  margin-top:0;
}

.hov:hover li:nth-child(even){
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(30px) rotateX(0deg);
  margin-top:0;
}
```

And then it seem really close to the other effect.

UPDATE:

The example [here](http://cdpn.io/nieox).

```css
nav{

}

ul,li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  
}
.main li{
  list-style:none;
  background: blue;
  width:100px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;

  line-height: 30px;
  /*margin-top: -30px;*/
  
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  
}

.main li:nth-child(odd){
  
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.main li:nth-child(even){
  margin-top:-65px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.main {
  
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.hov:hover .main {
  
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
}

.hov:hover li:nth-child(odd){
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(30px) rotateX(0deg);
  margin-top:0;
}

.hov:hover li:nth-child(even){
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(30px) rotateX(0deg);
   margin-top:0;
}

.main li:first-child{
  margin-top:0;
}

.hov{
  position:relative;
  height: 40px;
  width:112px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style:none;
  z-index:2;
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <li class="hov">Hover Me!
    <ul class="main">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```